# Transform coordinates from ITRF2014 (2020.39) to ITRF2008 (2010.0) using PROJ4?

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, proj, transform

Due to the fact that I cannot convert the coordinates obtained at epoch 2023.39, X = 1710698.054 meters; Y = 3046082.270 meters; Z = 5318707.282 meters, I still cannot understand how to use in this library the rate of change of coordinates Vx, Vy, Vz, which are equal to: -25.08 mm/year, 8.57mm/year, 3.16mm/year, but it's okay, I calculated them myself and got these: 1710698.3741m 3046082.1606m 5318707.2417m for epoch 2011.0, but now the problem arises that I can not get them transformed into itrf2008, knowing the Helmert parameters, my code is as follows:

```
cs2cs +t_epoch=2011.0 +proj=geocent +ellps=GRS80 +no_defs +type=crs +to +proj=geocent
+ellps=GRS80 +no_defs +type=crs +step +proj=helmert +x=0.0016 +y=0.0019 +z=0. 0024 +rx=0 +ry=0 +rz=0 +s=-2e-05 +dx=0 +dy=0 +dz=-0.0001 +drx=0 +dry=0 +drz=0 +ds=3e-05 +t_epoch=2010.0 +step +convention=position_vector -f "%.4f"
```

But it just doesn't count them, outputting the same coordinates that I send to it eventually...
I have recently started to master this library.

Comment: Is 2011.0 the epoch for the transformation? If not, I think you could convert the data to the transformation's epoch then use the ITRF2014 to ITRF2008 transformation without any time/velocity parameter values.